# calculate percent change of two uint32 numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I try to calculate the percent change of two numbers like that

```
UInt32 OriginInt=32654, NewInt=4256321445;
(NewInt - OriginInt ) * 100 / UInt32.MaxValue;
```

this code gives me zero every time.

Comment: Why are you dividing by the maxvalue of the type?

Comment: I need to calculate the amount of change relative to the total amount

Comment: But what does the maximal possible value of the type have to do with that?

Comment: Usually, you would divide by `OriginInt`, not `UInt32.MaxValue`.

Comment: Yes usually divide by OriginInt, but I need this type of calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the basic shape of the expression is correct (so, you want to express the change as a percentage of `UInt32.MaxValue`, not as a percentage of the old or new value), the problem is that multiplying the difference by 100 overflows. It could be fixed by temporarily using an `ulong` like this:

```
uint OriginInt=32654, NewInt=4256321445;
(uint)(((ulong)NewInt - OriginInt) * 100 / uint.MaxValue);
```

The result is 99.

Of course since this is still integer arithmetic, it will still be the case that the result is rounded down, so a small percentages (below 1) would still result in zero.

Answer (score 1):

dividing two integers **always** results in an integer. You must use a type cast

like this

```
var result = (double)(NewInt - OriginInt) * 100 / UInt32.MaxValue;
```

or this

```
var result = (NewInt - OriginInt) * 100.0 / UInt32.MaxValue;
```

result: `99.099445901601442`

Answer (score 0):

Thats understandable, since you re dividing by the maximun number of the UInt32, so best case scenario the answer would be one, and since you re not casting it to a float, decimal or double, then its giving you 0 which is the integer part of 0.xxxx. Here is how to get the value.

```
        UInt32 OriginInt = 32654, NewInt = 4256321445;
        decimal result = Math.Round((decimal)(NewInt - OriginInt) * 100 / UInt32.MaxValue, 2);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But if what you want to get is the % of growth from the initial number to the new number as you say in the question what you should do is this

```
        var result = (OriginInt - NewInt) / OriginInt * 100;

        Console.WriteLine($"{result}%");
```